# ConnectionPatch breaks constrained_layout when crossing axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a ConnectionPatch between two axes in the same figure, following [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/userdemo/connect_simple01.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-connect-simple01-py), with `plt.subplots(..., constrained_layout=True)`. I see all the patches, but the axes are smaller and squished off to the sides.

[1](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/userdemo/connect_simple01.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-connect-simple01-py) https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/userdemo/connect_simple01.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-connect-simple01-py

I downloaded the example code and executed it in a conda environment with matplotlib 3.1.1 and python 3.6.7.  I've run this example in both a jupyter notebook and as a conventional python script with similar results. If I comment out the add_artist call on line 26, the layout looks normal again.

Oddly, when I ran this on a different machine earlier today it worked fine.

I expect a layout like that shown in the example:
[image: expected]

Instead I get an image that has the axes shrunk and off to the side:

[image: actual]

Comment: The problem is the second arrow which is defined in terms of two different data coordinate systems. I'm not sure what *"Oddly, when I ran this on a different machine earlier today it worked fine."* means, so if you can clarify the versions in use and possible other differences, it might help. Else, feel free to [report it](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues), but I'm not sure if anything can be done about it.

Comment: Right, if I get rid of the second arrow it looks right, but that's the feature I'm most interested in. I'll update the question tomorrow with package versions for my work computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking a bit about it, I'm now convinced that there is no reasonable way to perform layout management for ConnectionPatches that are defined in data coordinates of two different axes.

The solution must hence be to exclude such artist from the layout manager.

```
fig, (ax, ...) = plt.subplots(..., contrained_layout=True)
# ....
con = ConnectionPatch(...)
con.set_in_layout(False)
ax.add_artist(con)
```

Alternatively you can use tight_layout before adding the artist, like

```
fig, (ax, ...) = plt.subplots(...)
# ....
con = ConnectionPatch(...)

fig.tight_layout()
ax.add_artist(con)
```

Comment: That’s likely it.  The example doesn’t use layout management but perhaps the OP has something in their matplotlibrc that is turning it on?

Comment: Yes I do have constrained_layout in my matplotlibrc, I forgot to include that in the question. The `set_in_layout` solution worked like a charm. Thanks so much. I've found that ``tight_layout()`` changes the figure dimensions when calling ``save_fig`` to a pgf file. Beyond this MWE I'm preparing figures for journal publication so the figure size matters. I'll submit an issue to mpl on github to add a note to the document about this. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You can also try adding the artist as a figure artist.

Comment: This solution is now in the documentation. The docs also suggest adding the patch to the figure instead of the axes: `fig.add_artist(con)` thus avoiding the need for `set_in_layout`.